# Standard error of probability estimate

Tags: standard-error

Take a look at Table 1 on page 268 in http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/teaching/thesis/DixonColes.pdf

It says at the end of the previous page that the standard errors are computed "on the basis of an underlying multinomial model". The sample size is $6629$ (also mentioned on the previous page).

If I understand things correctly the standard error should be $$\sqrt{\frac{p\cdot(1-p)}{n}},$$ but computing them in this way I can't have them match the results in the paper.
For example the entry 33.4 (0.74).
I get that the standard error should be $$100 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{0.334 \cdot 0.666}{6629}} = 0.57927707090437$$
(the factor 100 just to norm to percentages).
Have I misunderstood something here?

Comment: It's not clear to me how those standard errors were obtained (but I didn't read the whole paper). I came up with one or two possibilities, but I was able to show they couldn't explain the rest of the same row. Hopefully someone else can do better.

Comment: I have the same question. Can someone tell me how to calculate Standard Error belonging to a probability?